# How to create a scrollable textarea with scrolling background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, textarea

I would like to add a background image to the textarea that scrolls along with the content.  I'm programming in HTML/JavaScript/CSS specifically for mobile Safari.

I've attempted a variety of things but nothing seems to work. 
I tried placing the textarea on top of the image and then scrolling the background image whenever the textarea is scrolled.  It works more or less fine when I'm typing text, but the native scrollbars (which I don't want to get rid of) make it look a wreck on mobile Safari.

I tried using a contentEditable div container but that seemed to throw problems too (again with the scrolling).

Is it possible to have a textarea with native scrolling with a background image that scrolls?

Comment: now check my answer and let me know if i am lagging somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background image can be applied to an input or text element as shown:

[check the fiddle jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/XxZ8h/)

html

```
<div class="outer">
     <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
```

css

```
.outer { width: 310px; height: 250px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #666; -webikit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden  }

textarea{
    background: #fff url('http://www.toddle.com/images/300_words_background.gif') 0 -220px no-repeat;
    width: 302px;padding:5px; height:99em;
}
```

**Note:** The difference between the two is that the content within the div (assuming it's coded correctly) will be included as search engine usable text whereas the textarea content will not.

Comment: I saw the background-attachment property, but it doesn't seem to work in any of the browsers that I've tried.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/wNytU/

Comment: which version of browser are yo using?

Comment: Google Chrome (most up to date version) and Mobile Safari on a brand new ipad3.

Comment: you can add cols="you want"  rows="you want" wrap='off' to textarea and put something in textarea so you can get the scroll

Comment: your fiddle is working fine just check by writing a enough long paragraph

Comment: and if you are using the textarea to get the input from the user its good but if you showing the content please check  the **note** above in my answer

Comment: please wait 1 min ill give you exact my answer

Comment: ok.  Every browser I've tried, Chrome, mobile safari, Firefox doesn't have the textarea background image scrolling when I add text.

Comment: I think your edit might be fine.  It was a bit screwy on mobile safari, but once I added a -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch to the outer container, I believe that took care of the issue.   I'll put it into my actual code and see if there are any bugs with this.  If not, then I'll give you the check.